# Mailman server crashes on POP3 authentication failure in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pop3, mailman-gem

I am having a problem - mailman crashes each time after POP3 authentication failure occurs.  I have an exception catcher as below but this appear doesn't work:

```
Mailman::Application.run do
    default do
        begin
          **Some code here**
        rescue Exception => e
          **Calling logger method**
        end
    end
end
```

However mailman fails almost every day on this error and dies:

> ERROR -- : -ERR [SYS/TEMP] Temporary system problem. Please try again
>   later. (Net::POPAuthenticationError)

I am using Gmail's POP3 and I am sure that server has internet access (using AWS) and I a have monitor which checks if server online every 5 minutes. But even if it goes offline, is it possible to keep mailman checking for e-mails even if POP3 auth fails?

Comment: Does that gmail account has 2 factor authentication enabled?

Comment: Yes. Two factor auth is enabled and I am using generated Application password for my app. Normally it works, however intermitently fails on POP Authentication.

Comment: Gmail has limit on number of POP and IMAP connection limit for an account. Example, for IMAP the limit is 10 parallel connection. If the user has configured IMAP in 10 client (outlook, thunderbird, ..) then the 11th connection will fail.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explanation. But this POP3 account is not used anywhere else. Any other suggestions? ;)

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/53fvtqnOY84

Can you re-verify your client's access via the web and try again

Comment: That error message looks simply like the server hiccuped.

Comment: @Sivalingam thank you! Disabling captcha from within the gmail account seems to be resolved the issue. It works stable two days so far. Cheers